# Erasing 1 byte of external Flash memory (winbond)

Tags: arduino-nano, audio, memory-usage, flash

i'm trying to use an external flash memory Winbond 25q64jvsiq for my Arduino Nano based project for audio recording purposes, to have extra memory for recording 1 byte audio samples, since Arduino nano SRAM memory is too small (8kb), to store at least 1 second of 8 kHz 8 bit samples audio. I'm trying to understand the basics of  bytes storing in my external memory. I'm using SPIMemory library for that, and i can't find a function to erase 1 byte, there is only sectorErase() function. So i wonder is it even possible to erase a single byte of external memory?

Here is a part of code where i try to rewrite (erase one byte and write a new one) a next byte when the button pressed, but when it erase a sector it erases not the one byte but all bytes behind it, and i want to manipulate it more accurate, and erase only one byte:

```
if(!digitalRead(5)){      //button pressed
     if(e<3){
      e++;
      flash.eraseSector(count);    //erasing a byte
      flash.writeByte(count,e,NOERRCHK); // write a new value
      }  else {  
        e=0;
        flash.eraseSector(count);
        flash.writeByte(count,e,NOERRCHK);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

For a flash chip, no it's not possible to erase a single byte.

The closest you can do is to read an entire sector into memory, erase that sector, modify your in-memory copy, then write the sector back.

You would be better using an SPI SRAM or PSRAM chip instead of a flash chip.